# How do you decide if it is worth it to continue working on project when you know that another person works on the same project too?

Tags: professionalism, software-industry

One of my co-workers mentioned an old PC game and said that it would be great if we (me and my colleague) could remake one for windows phone few days ago. But the project is too small for two programmers and both of us have enough skill to create this game.

Who should back off in this situation?  If one of us was told before the other, it would be easy to decide but now I am confused.

*Note:* I'd love to work together but it seems that he does not want it.

And in general, how do you decide if it is worth it to continue working on a project when you know that another person works on the same thing and neither of you has any crucial advantage?

Comment: This is a job function decision not a general workplace decision as such is off topic. But you have to use the same criteria you would use on any other business decision to decide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how to decide does it worth to continue working on project when you know that another person works on the same too and neither of you has any crucial advantage?

I assume you do this as a hobby. Therefore, if you want to do it, go ahead. Since your colleague wants it to it on his own, you can start your own version.

On the other hand, if this is for a job, then there should be a person in charge, telling who do what.

Comment: No, it's not for a job. Just a side project. Thanks for answer.